# Converting cURL to fetch with auth, multipart/form-data, and json

Tags: javascript, curl, multipartform-data, form-data, fetch-api

I was struggling converting some cURL into javascript.

I was using this to convert the curl to php - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ - this tool is absolutely awesome. Howver I was having a hard time with javascript.

My curl is this:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}:{password}"
--form metadata="{
  \"part_content_type\":\"audio/wav\",
 }"
--form upload="@audio-me.wav"
"https://my.url.here"
```

I am trying this, but the endpoint is giving me failure, the details are not given, the browser actually throws a:

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

This is what I put togather:

```
let metadata = { part_content_type: 'audio/wav' };

let data = new FormData();
data.append('upload', blob, 'audio-me.wav');
data.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(metadata));
fetch('https://my.url.here', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64_encode(username + ':' + password)
    },
    body: data
}).then(x=>console.log('success:', x)).catch(z=>console.error('fail:',z));

function base64_encode (stringToEncode) { // eslint-disable-line camelcase
//  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/base64_encode/
// original by: Tyler Akins (http://rumkin.com)
// improved by: Bayron Guevara
// improved by: Thunder.m
// improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)
// improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)
// improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
// bugfixed by: Pellentesque Malesuada
// improved by: Indigo744
//   example 1: base64_encode('Kevin van Zonneveld')
//   returns 1: 'S2V2aW4gdmFuIFpvbm5ldmVsZA=='
//   example 2: base64_encode('a')
//   returns 2: 'YQ=='
//   example 3: base64_encode('✓ à la mode')
//   returns 3: '4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='
// encodeUTF8string()
// Internal function to encode properly UTF8 string
// Adapted from Solution #1 at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding
var encodeUTF8string = function (str) {
    // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded UTF-8,
    // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
    // can be fed into the base64 encoding algorithm.
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
    function toSolidBytes (match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1)
    })
}
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof window.btoa !== 'undefined') {
    return window.btoa(encodeUTF8string(stringToEncode))
    }
} else {
    return new Buffer(stringToEncode).toString('base64')
}
var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='
var o1
var o2
var o3
var h1
var h2
var h3
var h4
var bits
var i = 0
var ac = 0
var enc = ''
var tmpArr = []
if (!stringToEncode) {
    return stringToEncode
}
stringToEncode = encodeUTF8string(stringToEncode)
do {
    // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = stringToEncode.charCodeAt(i++)
    o2 = stringToEncode.charCodeAt(i++)
    o3 = stringToEncode.charCodeAt(i++)
    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3
    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f
    h4 = bits & 0x3f
    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmpArr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4)
} while (i < stringToEncode.length)
enc = tmpArr.join('')
var r = stringToEncode.length % 3
return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3)
}
```

May you please advise if I did this conversion wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You did notice that you have `audio/wave` rather than `audio/wav`? Also, Have you checked in your browser's developer tools whether the request actually matches what you want/need? Have you tried with postman?

Comment: You're also missing `Basic` in your `Authorization` header.

Comment: Also note that I don't think you really need much more than a very straightforward `btoa` for the base64 conversion.

Comment: Thanks @jcaron - I tried up vote all three of your comments but I don't have enough rep yet. The missing `Basic` and `wave` were typos when I was writing the question. I fixed it up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

When you send `FormData` with the `fetch(…)` method you don’t need to manually set the `Content-Type` request header. See [the relevant part of the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract):

> **↪ FormData**
>   Set *action* to an action that runs the `multipart/form-data` encoding algorithm, with *object* as *form data set* and with UTF-8 as the explicit character encoding.
>
> **Set *Content-Type* to `multipart/form-data; boundary=`**, followed by the `multipart/form-data` boundary string generated by the `multipart/form-data` encoding algorithm.

So the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` would be wrong anyway—since,  lacking the `boundary=…` part, it’s not properly formatted.

But by setting that manually in your code, I think you’re basically overwriting the properly-formatted `Content-Type` request header the browser is (per the Fetch spec requirements) already setting.